# How to load a model with tf.saved_model and call the predict function [TENSORFLOW 2.0 API]

Tags: tensorflow, model, save, load, predict

I'm very new to tensorflow and especially the 2.0 since there's not enough examples about that API but it seems much handy than the 1.x
So far I managed to train a linear model using the tf.estimator api, and then managed to save it using the tf.estimator.exporter.

After that I wanted to load this model using the tf.saved_model api and I think I succed doing that, but I have some doubts in my procedure so here's a quick look on my code :

so I have an array of features created using tf.feature_column api and it looks like this :

```
feature_columns = 
[NumericColumn(key='geoaccuracy', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='longitude', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='latitude', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 NumericColumn(key='bidfloor', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None),
 VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='adid', vocabulary_list=('115', '124', '139', '122', '121', '146', '113', '103', '123', '104', '147', '114', '149', '148'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0),
 VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='campaignid', vocabulary_list=('36', '31', '33', '28'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0),
 VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='exchangeid', vocabulary_list=('1241', '823', '1240', '1238'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0),
...]
```

after that I define an estimator using my feature columns array this way, and train it . untill here, no problem.

```
linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
```

after training my model I wanted to save it so here starts the doubts, here's how I proceeded but not sure it's the right way :

```
serving_input_parse = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns=feature_columns)

""" view of the variable : serving_input_parse = 
 {'adid': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
 'at': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
 'basegenres': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
 'bestkw': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
 'besttopic': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
 'bidfloor': FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None),
 'browserid': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
 'browserlanguage': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string)
 ...} """

# exporting the model :
linear_est.export_saved_model(export_dir_base='./saved',
 serving_input_receiver_fn=tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(serving_input_receiver_fn),
 as_text=True)
```

now I tried to load it, and I have no idea on how to use the loaded model to call a predict on it using raw data from pandas dataframe for instance

```
loaded = tf.saved_model.load('saved/1573144361/')
```

One more thing, I tried to take a look on the signature of the model but I can't really understand what's going on with my input shapes

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['classification']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/Tile:0
    outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/probabilities:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify

signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['all_class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/Tile:0
    outputs['all_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/Tile_1:0
    outputs['class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/ExpandDims:0
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/str_classes:0
    outputs['logistic'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/logistic:0
    outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/weighted_sum:0
    outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/probabilities:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

signature_def['regression']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['outputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/logistic:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/regress

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/Tile:0
    outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/probabilities:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify
```

Comment: Check solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959582/saving-loading-and-predicting-from-a-tensorflow-estimator-model-2-0/60230173#comment118347400_60230173

Answer (score 2):

The `saved_model.load(...)` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load) demonstrates the basic mechanism like this:

```py
imported = tf.saved_model.load(path)
f = imported.signatures["serving_default"]
print(f(x=tf.constant([[1.]])))
```

I'm still new to this myself but `serving_default` seems to be the default signature when using `saved_model.save(...)`.

(My understanding is that `saved_model.save(...)` doesn't save the model, it saves the graph. In order to interpret the graph, you need to explicitly store "signatures" the define operations on the graph. If you don't do it explicitly then "serve_default" will be your only signature.)

I've provided an implementation below. There are a few details worth noting:

1. The input **needs** to be a tensor; so I needed to manually make the conversion.
2. The output is a dictionary. The documentation described it as "A trackable object with a signatures attribute mapping from signature keys to functions."

In my case, the key to the dictionary was a relatively arbitrary "dense_83". This seemed a bit... specific. So I generalized the solution to ignore the key using an iterator:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
input_data = tf.constant(input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
prediction_tensors = signature_collection.signatures["serving_default"](input_data)
for _, values in prediction_tensors.items():
    predictions = values.numpy()[0]
    return predictions
raise Exception("Expected a response from predict(...).")
```

Comment: Big pleasure, @ThinkTeamwork. This community has helped me out so much. I'm happy to pay back a little.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the saved_model_cli command line tool for the last section of output.  From that you have a "predict" function which shows the inputs types, column, etc.  When I do this, I see all my input columns.  In your case, it simply shows one input which is a string named examples.  This does not look correct.

Here is an excerpt from output of `$ saved_model_cli show --dir /somedir/export/exporter/123456789 --all`.  In the output the dots show deleted rows since they look similar.

```
signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['feature_num_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_29:0
...
...
 The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['all_class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/Tile:0
    outputs['all_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: dnn/head/predictions/Tile_1:0
...
...
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is very interesting, can you share the code on how you proceed to generate this saved model ? did you use tf.estimator api for your model ? because i tried it with tf.keras and it actually produce the good signature but i'm struggling with the tf.estimator ones ...

Comment: I used an estimator.  I’m thinking perhaps you are using a single string as your input.  So perhaps I’m incorrect.  I’m learning as well so keep that in mind.  I don’t understand why you have six or more features but your predict function as one feature which is a string. Does your servingbinput function have one or multiple parameters?

Comment: Well my serving input does have multiple parameters and more than six actually, I was more expecting something like you had

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I found an alternative with `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model()`. Here is an example

##### To create, train, and save the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

## create a model
mdl = tf.keras.Sequential(...)
mdl.compile(...)

## train it
mdl.fit(...)

## save it
mdl.save('trained-model-file')
```

##### To load the saved model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

## load it with same file path
mdl = tf.keras.models.load_model('trained-model-file')

## predict the data
mdl.predict(...)
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/save-and-load-models-in-tensorflow/